# creating absolute URLs that work on both localhost and live site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to populate a Literal control with a URL that will work on both my local machine and the live website.

For now, this is what I have:

```
string TheHost = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
string ThePath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
string TheProtocol = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme;

string TheURL = "<a href=\"" + TheProtocol + "://" + TheHost + "/ThePageName\">SomeText</a>"
```

The URL that works when I type it manually in the browser looks like this:

```
http://localhost:12345/ThePageName
```

but when I run the above code it comes out as

```
localhost/ThePageName
```

What do I need to change so that on my local machine I output

```
http://localhost:12345/ThePageName
```

and on the live site I get

```
http://www.example.com/ThePageName
```

Comment: You also should use `UriBuilder` instead of string concatenation...

Comment: What is Url.Port going to look like when I go live on mysite.com?

Comment: Why do you need the domain name? Is this a multi tenant website?

Comment: @Phill: not sure, I just to extract http://localhost:12345 when I'm on my local machine and http://www.example.com when I'm in production and then just add /ThePageName to the result.

Comment: Just make all your urls relative to the root, i.e `/about` or `/products/123` and you will be fine.

Comment: @Phill: no, that's the whole point, I DON'T want relative URLs

Comment: Why do you want absolute URLs? Other than to add bloat to the HTML for large page sizes?

Comment: @Phill: because they work better for SEO purposes. I use relative URLs to load CSS and js files.

Comment: No they do not @frenchie, it makes absolutely no difference if its absolute or relative.

Comment: The only relatives you should avoid is relative to the current directory, i.e avoiding `../../contact` if you're relative to the root `/contact` then spiders cannot get confused and there is absolutely no difference between relative and absolute urls in SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that you've already got a `Uri` via the `Request` property - you don't need to do it all manually:

```
Uri pageUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, "/ThePageName");
```

Then build your tag using that - but ideally *not* just with string concatenation. We don't know enough about what you're using to build the response to say the best way to do it, but if you can use types which know how and when to use URI escaping etc, that will really help.

(I'd also suggest getting rid of your `The` prefix on every variable, but that's a somewhat different matter...)

Comment: Ok, thanks: it works like a charm! As for prefixing variables with "The", it's just my coding convention: if I'm referring to a variable in a class definition then I don't use The but if I'm using an instantiated object then I add "The".

Comment: @frenchie: Not sure exactly what you mean by "instantiated object" (local variable?) but it's certainly not a *common* coding convention - and one that you may well need to get out of the habit of if you work in a team which uses more conventional conventions. Glad the answer helped you though.

Answer (score 1):

Use [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to modify Urls. Assuming you need to just change path and keep all other parts the same:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url);
builder.Path = "MyOtherPage";
return builder.Uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to add the hostname for any of your urls in your site.

Just make all your url's relative to the root:

```
string TheURL = "<a href=\"/ThePageName\">SomeText</a>"
```

or

```
string TheURL = "<a href=\"/Products/12345\">SomeText</a>"
```

This will work fine regardless of the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Or Uri pageUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, "ThePageName"); without anti-slash

Comment: You should avoid referencing some answer with "or". If the answers are upvoted or downvoted they change position. And if your answer is the best then what does "or" reference to? If you want to reference some answer use @username.

Answer (score 0):

Just use different key/value in web.config and web.release.config files, and whenever you have to use it, read them from the web.config file.

Here is the example web.config:

```
    <add key="Url" value="http://localhost:58980/" />
```

Here is the example web.release.config:

```
    <add key="Url" value="http://example.com/" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

This may work. Works for me.